# How can I use openssl to get results from HTTP GET requests?

Tags: bash, scripting, openssl, shell-scripting

I need to use openssl to perform some HTTP GET requests in a shell script.  The line I'm using to do this right now is shown below.  This is parsing the content of an XML response of the following formats.

`<Result>success</Result>`

`<Result>failure</Result>`

```
echo -e "GET /test HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:$(hostname)\r\n\r\n" | openssl 2>&1 s_client -quiet -connect server-url:443 | grep -o -P --color '(?<=Result\>).*(?=\</Result)'
```

This works and returns the string 'success' or 'failure' accordingly.  The problem I'm facing is that the `openssl` command does not terminate after doing the GET request but instead sits there waiting on more input.  I believe this is due to the implicit `-ign_eof` which prevents automatic termination caused by the `-quiet` option.  I've tried using the `-no_ign_eof` option but that causes the `openssl` command to terminate before the GET request has received a response so I can't get the content of the response if I use that.

How can I modify this command so I can pass the GET request through stdin (required as I want to put this in a loop) but have the `openssl` command terminate after each request?

Comment: Why are you trying to abuse `openssl` for this, rather than using something more appropriate like `curl`?

Comment: Because curl isn't available on the system and I don't have permission to install it

Comment: Do yourself a favor, and go have a chat with the person who _does_ have permission to install it.

Comment: I intend to but that doesn't help me get this workaround up and running...

Comment: If you can't get `CURL` there is `wget` you could abuse bit better for it you can use the info at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12120935/wget-output-document-and-headers-to-stdout

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you *really* should be doing is using a tool designed for fetching Web resources, such as `curl`, `wget`, or libwww-perl's `GET` command. If nothing is available, you should have your system administrator install something appropriate.

With that out of the way...

The `openssl` command does not terminate because the web server didn't close the connection.

Remember that by default HTTP keeps connections open after each request as a performance optimization. Once one request finishes, another request can be sent over the same connection, rather than closing and reopening a new connection.

If you want to instruct the server to close the connection instead, you can send the `Connection: close` HTTP header.

Comment: As mentioned in the comments on the question, unfortunately it is proving difficult to get open source tools installed on this AIX system and `openssl` seems to be the only tool available to me to do this right now.  I've tried your suggestion and it works.  Thanks

Comment: As a _technical_ matter it's very easy to install the tools. I expect your roadblocks are entirely _political_ in nature.

Comment: yes they are, IBM even supply a list of open source tools on their website that includes curl http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/power/software/aix/linux/toolbox/alpha.html

Comment: Remember, and remind anyone who is in a position to listen, that workarounds like this ultimately _cost_ money.

Comment: Note: if you use POST, don't forget to include the request body (duh!)

Answer (score 1):

IBM uses Perl for bootstrapping downloads, and I would recommend using Perl until you can get approval to install curl properly, because it is bundled with the operating system. Specifically, their [dnf_aixtoolbox.sh](https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/dnf_aixtoolbox.sh) script uses `lwp-download` to download the `rpm.rte` package in lines like this:

```
    LDR_CNTRL=MAXDATA=0x80000000@DSA /usr/opt/perl5/bin/lwp-download https://public.dhe.ibm.com/aix/freeSoftware/aixtoolbox/ezinstall/ppc/dnf_bundle_aix_73.tar
```

While you're not trying to download a file, documentation on the [LWP library](https://metacpan.org/pod/LWP) provides a number of different examples for different uses.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple (but probably worse) solution would be to use HTTP/1.0 instead of HTTP/1.1.

Comment: It might work, but new-ish http servers sometimes can't handle 1.0.

Comment: @kubanczyk I have yet to come across an http server that cannot handle HTTP/1.0. A much more likely problem would be an http server that requires a `Host` header and a client that only sends the `Host` header when using HTTP/1.1. But ultimately the reason using HTTP/1.0 would help here is that it has different default behavior regarding closing the connection compared to HTTP/1.1. Adding a `Connection` header to the request would address that.

Answer (score -1):

There is a new scenario that brings up several of the points discussed in this thread previously. 
 One is related to curl, the other related to tlsv1.3

First, I was using curl and found that curl will interpret a '#' as the start of a new URL.  I have found others who have identified this same issue with curl using other special characters.  In this case, the URL is truncated and curl fails.

### Heading

The precise problem is using nonconforming characters to extend the URL name.  Web developers are adding data after the ".html".  My encounter is with the
`---------.html#<date>`. 
 As entered, curl will truncate the URL at the #.  If I encode it `-------.html%23<date>`, then paste the encoded URL into the website via a browser, it encodes the encoded characters again with results in "no page found."

Web developers are attaching data to URLs so instead of sending a new webpage each time a user requests a table change (frequently a table) the webpage can be updated by sending just the table data via JSON and not the entire webpage.

I don't see getting curl changed anytime soon.  Thus, using OpenSSL to bring up URLs is necessary if such features are to be tested.
I was able to find an unsecure website that happens to use # in the server paths.  I tested this using OpenSSL and it completed successfully.

```sh
echo -e "GET /#/Methods HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: eu.httpbin.org\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n" | openssl s_client -quiet -state -connect eu.httpbin.org:443
```

Therefore, it can conclude that OpenSSL does not treat `'#'` as a special character in a URL.  Curl parses input as HTML where `'#'` is a special character related to a HTML anchor.

The second issue, which is somewhat related to the initial topic, is using this same OpenSSL technique with tlsv1.3.  There are no errors reported by OpenSSL, but it stops after the second "read R Block."

```sh
echo -e "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: cmegroup.com\r\nConnection: Close\r\n\r\n" | openssl 2>&1 s_client -CAfile firefoxCertBundle.pem -cert privClientCrt.pem -key privClient.key -tls1_3 -ciphersuites TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384 -quiet -state -connect cmegroup.com:443
```

```
    SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server hello
    SSL_connect:TLSv1.3 read encrypted extensions
    depth=2 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, OU = www.digicert.com, CN = DigiCert Global 
    Root CA
    verify return:1
    depth=1 C = US, O = DigiCert Inc, CN = DigiCert SHA2 Secure Server CA
    verify return:1
    depth=0 C = US, ST = Illinois, L = Chicago, O = Chicago Mercantile Exchange Inc, 
    CN = www.cmegroup.com
    verify return:1
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server certificate
    SSL_connect:TLSv1.3 read server certificate verify
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read finished
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write change cipher spec
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write finished
    SSL_connect:SSL negotiation finished successfully
    SSL_connect:SSL negotiation finished successfully
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket
    SSL_connect:SSL negotiation finished successfully
    SSL_connect:SSL negotiation finished successfully
    SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS read server session ticket
```

Comment: The problem here is that `#` **is a special character**. Nothing after the # is intended to be sent to the server. It is interpreted client side only. It does not make sense to attempt to send it to the server.

Comment: please check RFC3986, you'll find that [fragments (portion of URI that's after the #)](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#page-24) is dereferenced solely by the useragent (e.g. browser). second, try adding `Connection: keep-alive` and `Accept: text/html;q=0.8` on your `openssl s_client` request, you'll find the server replies with 301.